# How to Mock a missing attribute

Tags: python, mocking

I have a line of code that is:

```
if not hasattr(class.a, u'c'):
    return
```

How do I mock out class so that class.a.c returns False for hasattr?

If I do this:

```
>>> from mock import MagicMock
>>> mock_class = MagicMock(spec=[u'a'])
>>> hasattr(mock_class, u'a')
True
>>> hasattr(mock_class, u'b')
False
>>> hasattr(mock_class.a, u'c')
True
```

Although I dont spec class.a.c, its being mocked!!!

Comment: Why not removing it with [delattr](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=delattr#delattr)?

Comment: I used: del mock_class.a.c in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually `mock_class.a` will create another MagicMock, which don't have a spec. The only way I can think of is to assign the attribute `a` of the `mock_class` with another MagicMock with spec, like this:

```
mock_class = MagicMock(spec=[u'a'])
mock_class.a = MagicMock(spec=[u'a'])
hasattr(mock_class.a, u'c')  # returns False
```

Also if you have some real objects you want to mock, there is a possibility to do some [recursive autospecing](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#autospeccing).

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this but it didn't work, but trying your example worked!

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the attribute, which will cause `hasattr` to return `False`.

From the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#deleting-attributes):

```
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> hasattr(mock, 'm')
True
>>> del mock.m
>>> hasattr(mock, 'm')
False
>>> del mock.f
>>> mock.f
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: f
```

For your specific example, since `mock_class.a` is another Mock, you can do `del mock_class.a.c`.